# Activer admin - user logout and admin as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, logout

I use device and omniauth to login in my site using some provider as twitter and active admin to manage the user.I have two tabs on browser one with twitter user and another with admin, when i logout in some of then the other tab was logout as well, this behavior is normal?

Answer (score 0):

A single browser will share a common session among various tabs and windows.  Logging out in one tab, will destroy the session keys and invalidate the session for the other tab as well.  The only way to avoid this is use a different browser (or machine).